# TransferSpreadsheet and getting IndentLevel

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm importing two colums of an excel file into an Access Database and simultaneously trying to get the IndentLevel of Column B (which contains a hierachy):

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "impTable", "C:\User\Admin\File.xlsx", False, "Sheet1!A:B"
```

Is it possible the TransferSpreadsheet to read out the IndentLevel? I prefer TransferSpreadsheet due the import speed in comperasion to Workbooks.Open.

Can anybody kindly give me any advices?

Comment: What is IndentLevel - a field? Edit question to show sample data and desired result. TransferSpreadsheet can't do anything beyond what is offered in its arguments.

Comment: The Indent level ist different for each cell -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/api/excel.range.indentlevel and with that information I can read out which level each entry has. E.g. Indent level 3 is the parent entry from Indent level 4

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Edit question to post sample data and desired result.

Comment: with indentlevel you can cout how many tabs you used. If you use no tab this would be the highest level the second line you will use one tab stop to show that this is the children entry. Can you kindly take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/api/excel.range.indentlevel?

Comment: TransferSpreadsheet ignores any formatting in Excel, so you are going to have to use Workbooks.Open, loop the data and check the IndentLevel as you import it.

Comment: I understand now and agree with @Applecore

Comment: ok sad but true. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

"TransferSpreadsheet ignores any formatting in Excel, so you are going to have to use Workbooks.Open"